# How to call custom method in django's admin template

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I've got a trouble: I can easily update my html template sending the "object_list" object and iterating it with

```
{%for item in object_list%}
#... some operation
{% endfor %}
```

However I don't know yet to do the same with my overriden admin-template in "template/admin/add_form.html": how to send and retrieve a method I added to my admin.py ModelAdmin custom class?

here there's my url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views as mysearch_views

from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import MySearch

# Admin custom
admin.sites.AdminSite.site_header = ‘to be decided’
admin.sites.AdminSite.site_title = ‘to be decided’
admin.sites.AdminSite.index_title = ‘to be decided’

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', mysearch_views.my_search, name="my_search"),
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', DetailView.as_view(model=MySearch, template_name="queries.html"), name="queries"),
url(r'^contacts', mysearch_views.contacts, name="contacts"),
url(r'^result-table', mysearch_views.create_table, name="results"),]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ModelAdmin` class, you can override the `add_view` method to add custom context data for the Add Form. There are other methods for other admin views: `change_view` for the Change Form, etc.

```
def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    extra_context = extra_context or {}
    extra_context['your_custom_data'] = self.your_custom_method()
    return super().add_view(request, form_url, extra_context=extra_context)
```

You can then use `{{ your_custom_data }}` in your overridden admin template.

`add_view` and the other related methods are documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.add_view).

Comment: Thanks! It works wonderfully, and yeah: documentation about this is not so exhaustive neither it's so easy to be found out